# Motivation behind Ito integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Today my professor introduced the Ito integral as a way to make sense of

$$\int \sigma(u) \cdot "noise"du$$

where noise is modeled as Brownian motion. He then said:

> With Riemann integrals you can approximate with rectangles to get the
>   area. But take a look at the plot of a brownian motion; you can't do
>   it. It's a fractal (it does not get smoothed if you "zoom in"), so
>   good luck drawing rectangles with that

Which struck me weird as the Brownian path is continuous and hence Riemann integrable.

I guess it was just a simplification, but I wonder now what exactly goes horribly wrong if we define $$\int \sigma(u) B(\omega, u) du$$
for a fixed $\omega$ (so that the integral depends on $\omega$) as the usual Riemann integral

Thank you!

Comment: Recall that the sample paths are continuous almost surely - given a fixed $\omega$, it is not necessarily true that the corresponding sample path is continuous.

Comment: @Math1000 Okay, then define for thos $\omega$ the integral to be equal to $0$.. I mean equality almost everywhere usually (almost always? :-P) is not such a dramatic deal-breaker, is it?

Comment: Integrals such as $\int\sigma(u)B(u)du$ with $\sigma$ smooth are **not** a motivation to Itô's integral since, as you explain, $u\mapsto\sigma(u)B(u)$ is Riemann integrable. Rather, Itô introduced the notion of stochastic integrals to deal with integrals $\int\sigma(u)dB(u)$, which are problematic  since $B$ is continuous but not regular.

Comment: @Math1000 This is offtopic.

Comment: @Did thank you very much. your comment and Henrik answer should have cleared that up ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem integrating a brownian motion *pathwise* with respect to a 
continuous (say) integrand. This is because a brownian motion has continuous almost everywhere sample paths.

In the Ito integral the brownian motion is used as an *integrand*, i.e. it has the form $\int_{[0,T]} f(s,\omega) dW(s,\omega)$. One can show that if every continuous function is Riemann integrable with respect to some integrand $g$, then $g$ has to be of bounded variation. But it is a well known fact that the sample paths of brownian motion do not have bounded variation.